# noob question regarding twitter oauth

Tags: python, oauth, twitter

I'm unfamiliar with the new oauth system. I wanted to crawl the status updates of my friends, and their friends' (if permissions allow) with my specified account credentials using the python-twitter api.

With the new oauth authentication, does it means that I have to first register an application with twitter before I can use api?

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say "crawl tweets"?

Comment: @Tim, I suppose I wanted to find my friends' status updates as well as their immediate friends'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, thats right. You need to register it and connect "grant access" it with your twitter id, if you want, for example, post something on your twitter wall. Also see "connections" in your twitter id.

Comment: you mean,even for read access with my own account, I need to register an application? Great, what do I use for "application website" and "organization"

Comment: Yes, thats because an app is in the first step completely separeted from any twitter id. Therefore its also possible to change your twitter password, without modifying the app, after you granted access. Without oauth, (in the old basic auth api) this would not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

For use api you must register your aplication or use GET methods to post into twi through  web interface.